# How to make tabindex localized within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I'm trying to make examples of what is bad practice in terms of accessibility. I have three examples that have to do with Keyboard Focus. The first example is that you aren't able to see focus on a set of buttons. The second example is that focus order isn't logical. In order to accomplish the second and third examples, I have to add in the tabindex attribute to some of the tags.

I'm having a little trouble understanding how I might be able to tab through the first 4 buttons (in order), then move onto the form (in order of the first field, the submit, the third field, and then second field), and then finally onto a div of links (in order, but has a loop).

What happens currently is, tabbing through the first 4 buttons works, but then focus goes to the url address bar and then onto the input fields. I want the focus order to go from div to div. I'll also note that this will be in a tabpanel on a website, so I want this to be pretty isolated.

I hope that makes a little sense, I don't have too much experience in webdev. Here's the Codepen and html for reference! Thank you!

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZyaMrP

```
<style>
button:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
</style>

<p>Unfocusable buttons</p>
<div class="buttons">
  <button>button 1</button>
  <button>button 2</button>
  <button>button 3</button>
  <button>button 4</button>
</div>

<p>Unintuitive Focus Order</p>
<div class="inputs">
  <form>
    <label>input 1</label>
    <input type="text" tabindex="1"><br>
    <label>input 2</label>
    <input type="text" tabindex="4"><br>
    <label>input 3</label>
    <input type="text" tabindex="2"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="3">
  </form>
</div>

<p>Focus Trap (Loop)</p>
<div class="links">
  <a href="#" tabindex="5">link 1</a>
  <a href="#" tabindex="6">link 2</a>
  <a href="#" tabindex="7" onFocus="this.tabindex=4;" onBlur="this.tabindex=7;">link 3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/awVRmm

In your inline javascript, you need to make sure to use this.tabIndex, as this.tabindex is not a valid property.

```
<p>Unfocusable buttons</p>
<div class="buttons">
  <button>button 1</button>
  <button>button 2</button>
  <button>button 3</button>
  <button>button 4</button>
</div>
<p>Unintuitive Focus Order</p>
<div class="inputs">
  <form>
    <label>input 1</label>
    <input type="text" onFocus="this.tabIndex+=1;"><br>
    <label>input 2</label>
    <input type="text" onFocus="this.tabIndex+=3;"><br>
    <label>input 3</label>
    <input type="text" onFocus="this.tabIndex+=4;"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onFocus="this.tabIndex+=2;">
  </form>
</div>
<p>Focus Trap (Loop)</p>
<div class="links">
  <a href="#" tabindex="5">link 1</a>
  <a href="#" tabindex="6">link 2</a>
  <a href="#" tabindex="7" onFocus="this.tabIndex=4;" onBlur="this.tabIndex=7;">link 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! I missed that. Also, doesn't this just tab through the first 4 buttons, the first input field, and then go straight to the links? I still want the other two input fields and the submit button to be in the tab order (although not in-order).

Comment: Another question I had was, isn't the default tabindex always set to 0? So if you do this.tabIndex+=x (where x in a number), isn't that the same as saying tabindex = "x", but only once focus has been placed?

Comment: @landofall You are trapping the tab in the 2nd and 3rd links, so it will never proceed on the page, will just keep cycling because you are trapping it. Yes, default index is 0, unless it was already set. So if you do onFocus event, every time you focus, tab index is incremented.

Comment: Right, I want the links to keep cycling (to demonstrate what a keyboard trap is in my example), but for the first run through, I want to be able to tab through the first 4 buttons and the form and then get stuck in the loop. I think in the code pen, on the first run through, it tabs through the buttons, only the first input field, and then the links loop. My question was more on how to handle that properly. Thanks!